# Cannot access DB from .Net MVC WebApp

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've been trying to host a web app locally on one of my machines at home. I've been able to launch the server, access pages, etc, but whenever I try to load a page that requires access to the Db, I get the error below.
I just want to be able to manipulate the local SQL DB through a simple .net MVC web app/ web api. Everything otherwise works when debugging the app, guess that has something todo with the IIS express that runs to host the local Db.  I plan on keeping this server only accessible through local network, but I wouldn't mind taking a secure route incase I change my mind.

Tried:

- Changing connection strings to the sa user
- Added IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, and a custom HomeWebApp to the folders
  permissions, all with modify permissions
- Added user to the local dbs logins, IIS APPPOOL\HomeWebApp in the
  SQL Server manager

  ```
  ○ Server roles: Public
  ○ User Mapping: mapping the DB to the user with membership access:
      § db_datreader
      § db_datawriter
      § public
  ○ Status:
      § Permissions to connect: Grant
      § Login: Enabled
  ○ Server:
      § (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
  ○ Connection:
      § DesktopName\User(me/ Admin)
  ○ Checked to see if the SQLEXPRESS was running (it was)
  ```

There's so much more I tried, but due to the amount of troubleshooting options, they went undocumented. 
Sidenote: the db file is in another directory, with different folder permissions, if that matters.

First Error I was getting:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)
```

Changed setProfileEnvironment in the applicationhost.config to true, that fixed the first error, but gave me a different one afterwards

```
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"> 
        <!--To ensure you can access a webdb, setProfileEnviro to true, Its off for the time being.-->
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
```

New Error:

```
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\x\Desktop\HomeWebApp_n\HomeWebApp\ArduinoWebApp\App_Data\aspnet-ArduinoWebApp-20190313090314.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\x\Desktop\HomeWebApp_n\HomeWebApp\ArduinoWebApp\App_Data\aspnet-ArduinoWebApp-20190313090314.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

WebApp Web.Config connection settings:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\x\Desktop\HomeWebApp_n\HomeWebApp\ArduinoWebApp\App_Data\aspnet-ArduinoWebApp-20190313090314.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ArduinoWebApp-20190313090314;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Other solutions I'd found and tried that did not work:
    https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/
    https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674930/Configuring-IIS-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Server
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017
    [Connect to SQL Server database using Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488864/connect-to-sql-server-database-using-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)
    https://forums.iis.net/t/1213147.aspx?How+I+can+run+IIS+app+pool+by+domain+account+

Comment: Do you have you database scripted or in the `AttachDbFilename` location?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by scripted, like when the Db is created? There is a Db file located in the `AttachDbFileName`. And as I understand it, EntityFramework generates a script which in turn creates the Db, is that what you mean by scripted?

Comment: The location in `AttachDbFilename` is it in your machine at home?

Comment: Should be local, on the machine that the site is hosted. `AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\x\Desktop\HomeWebApp_n\HomeWebApp\ArduinoWebApp\App_Data\aspnet-ArduinoWebApp-20190313090314.mdf`